# Choose the XML node if child element exist and based on the value of a child element + SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath

I want to extract only those nodes which has a particular child and that child should have a value. 
  Ex :

```
   xmlDoc = <Report>
      <Version>
        <RecordId>1</RecordId>
        <Note>abcd</Note>
      </Version>
      <Version>
        <RecordId>2</RecordId>
        <Note>efgh</Note>
        <Rindicator>1</Rindicator>
      </Version>
    <Version>
        <RecordId>3</RecordId>
        <Note>ijkl</Note>
      <Rindicator>1</Rindicator>
      </Version>
    <Version>
        <RecordId>4</RecordId>
        <Note>ijkl</Note>
      <Rindicator>0</Rindicator>
      </Version>
    </Report>
```

The result should be

```
   <Report>
          <Version>
            <RecordId>2</RecordId>
            <Note>efgh</Note>
            <Rindicator>1</Rindicator>
          </Version>
        <Version>
            <RecordId>3</RecordId>
            <Note>ijkl</Note>
          <Rindicator>1</Rindicator>
          </Version>
        </Report>
```

I tried the following but not getting the expected results.

```
DECLARE @RindVal varchar(2) = '1'
 UPDATE #TempTable
 SET xmlDoc.modify('delete /*:Report/*:Version[*:Rindicator != sql:variable("@RindVal")]');
```

Comment: you could negate the Rindicator equality to the variable. This will include Version nodes which are missing a Rindicator element:  `.modify('delete /*:Report/*:Version[not(*:Rindicator = sql:variable("@RindVal"))]');`

Comment: Thank you that worked. If u can put it as answer I can mark it so.

Comment: ..@BumbleBee...:), you could post the answer (underlining the namespace wildcards) for reference. It could be very useful to anyone that runs into a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check it out the solution below. It is using XQuery and its FLWOR expression.

> SQL

```
-- DDL and sample data population. start
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, xmlDoc XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl (xmlDoc) VALUES
(N'<Report>
    <Version>
        <RecordId>1</RecordId>
        <Note>abcd</Note>
    </Version>
    <Version>
        <RecordId>2</RecordId>
        <Note>efgh</Note>
        <Rindicator>1</Rindicator>
    </Version>
    <Version>
        <RecordId>3</RecordId>
        <Note>ijkl</Note>
        <Rindicator>1</Rindicator>
    </Version>
    <Version>
        <RecordId>4</RecordId>
        <Note>ijkl</Note>
        <Rindicator>0</Rindicator>
    </Version>
</Report>');
-- DDL and sample data population. end

-- before
SELECT * FROM @tbl;

DECLARE @RindVal char(1) = '1';

UPDATE @tbl
SET xmlDoc = xmlDoc.query('<Report>
 {
     for $x in /Report/Version[(Rindicator/text())[1] eq sql:variable("@RindVal")]
     return $x
 }
 </Report>');

 -- after
 SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

Comment: thank u. Could you please point out What am I missing or doing wrong in the way I did.

Comment: (1) I don't understand why you tried to use a wildcard namespace prefix. (2) You can try to use the same construct as I did for the Rindicator element.

Comment: I am using wildcard namespace prefix because I have multiple  namespaces in the xml.

Comment: You need to learn how to provide a minimal reproducible sample while asking a question. Namespaces are a part of it.

Answer (score 1):

This should work too. Delete nodes with no Rindicator or with Rindicator's value different from 1 (as shown in your expected output).

```
update @XML set data.modify('delete //Version[not(Rindicator[.="1"])]')
```